# What is the geometric mean of the first hitting time distribution of Wiener process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, approximation, geometric-mean

I'm looking for an analytic formula. Approximate formulas are welcome, in which case I give more importance to simple and nice expressions rather than to precision of the approximation.

I'm looking for the geometric mean of the first hitting time distribution which can be computed as $\exp(E[\log(T)])$. The big difficulty for me is to compute $E[\log(T)]$.

**What I've got so far:**

1. I tried to compute the expectation explicitly by integrating

   $$E[\log(T)]=\int t e^t f_T(e^t) \mathrm{d}t$$

   where $f_T$ is the PDF of $T$. However, since $f_T$ already has a complex expression it is impossible to compute. I plugged the integral into Sympy but it came back without any simplification.
2. Using Fokker-Planck equation

   In fact a common way to compute moments and expectation of $T$ is to make use of Fokker-Planck equation to derive

   $$\frac{\partial G_T(t|\delta)}{\partial t}=\nu \frac{\partial G_T(t|\delta)}{\partial \delta} +\frac{1}{2}\sigma  \frac{\partial^2 G_T(t|\delta)}{\partial^2 \delta}$$

   where $G_T(t|\delta)$ is the survival function $p(T>t)$. From this we get

   $$-n M_T^{n-1}(\delta)= \nu \frac{\mathrm{d} M_T^{n}(\delta)}{\mathrm{d} \delta} +\frac{1}{2}\sigma  \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 M_T^n(\delta)}{\mathrm{d}^2 \delta} $$

   where $M^i$ is the $i$th moment of $T$ and $M^0=1$. From this one may compute $E[T]=M_T^1(\delta)$ by solving the corresponding differential equation.

   However, I'm looking for $E[U]$ with $U=\log(T)$. A corresponding equation would be

   $$\frac{\partial G_U(\log u |\delta)}{\partial u}=\nu \frac{\partial G_U(\log u |\delta)}{\partial \delta} +\frac{1}{2}\sigma  \frac{\partial^2 G_U(\log u|\delta)}{\partial^2 \delta}$$

   but this doesn't help me much since to obtain a recursive relation for $M_U$ I need an expression in terms of $G_U(u |\delta)$ not $G_U(\log u |\delta)$
3. Approximation

   Another option that I was looking into is to approximate the logarithm with

   $$\log (z)  = \frac{(z-1)^1}{1} - \frac{(z-1)^2}{2} + \frac{(z-1)^3}{3} - \frac{(z-1)^4}{4} + \cdots$$

   so that $E[\log T]$ would factorize as $E[\log T]= a E[T]+b E[T^2]+c E[T^3] +\cdots$, where the moments could be obtained from the recursive equation. I'm not sure whether the expectation of $\log T$ can be decomposed in this way. Even if it could, the solution looks messy.

   Anyway, that's what I've go so far. Maybe you have a suggestion how to tackle the problem.

**Background Information:**

1. Wiener process with drift

   The position of a particle at time $t$ is given by

   \begin{align}
   d_0 &= \delta  \\
   d_t &= \int_0^t v_h \mathrm{d} h  \\
   v_t &\sim \mathcal{N}(\nu,\sigma t)
   \end{align}

   where $\nu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}^+$ are the drift and diffusion parameters and $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$ is the starting position
2. First hitting time

   First hitting time is the time $T$ for which $d_t>\beta$ or $d_t<0$ while $0<d_h<\beta$ for $0<h<t$ with upper threshold at $\beta\in \mathbb{R}^+ $ and lower threshold at zero.